# how to take a txt file and split it into strings, getting rid of any floats or int

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to programming, using python 3.0.

I have to write a program that takes an input file name for a .txt file, reads the file but only reads certain words, ignoring the floats and integers and any words that don't match anything in another list.

Basically, I have wordsList and messages.txt. 
This program has to read through messages.txt (example of text:

> [41.298669629999999, -81.915329330000006] 6 2011-08-28 19:02:36 Work needs to fly by ... I'm so excited to see Spy Kids 4 with the love of my life ... ARREIC)

It then has to ignore all the numbers and search for whether or not any of the words in the message match the words in the wordsList and then match those words to a value(int) in the hvList.

What I have so far: (the wordsList and hvList are in another part of code that I don't think is necessary to show to understand what I'm trying to do (let me know if you do need it to help)

```
def tweetsvalues ():
    tweetwList = []
    tinputfile = open(tweetsinputfile,"r")
    for line in tinputfile:
        entries = line.split()
```

The last line, `entries = line.split()` is the one that needs to be changed I'm guessing.

Comment: You may find a regular expression usefule to look for words that consist solely of alphabetical characters (or whatever else your constraints are)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **split** is your best friend here.  You can also look up the documentation for the [is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) methods.  Although the full code is beyond the normal scope of StackOverflow, your central work will look something like

```
words = sentence.split()
good_words = [word for word in words if isalpha(word)]
```

This can be done in a "Pythonic" fashion using **filter**, removing punctuation, etc.  However, from the way you write in your posting, I suspect you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code that I wrote earlier today as a really basic spellchecker. I would answer your question more specifically but I do not have the time as of now. This should accomplish what you are looking for. The hard coded .txt file that I am opening contains a lot of english words that are spelled correctly. Feel free to supplement my ideas into your work as needed, but make sure to understand all of the code you are using, otherwise I would only be hindering your learning by giving this code to you. In your case, you would likely want to output all of the words regardless of their spelling, in my code, I am only outputting incorrectly spelled words. Feel free to ask any questions

```
    #---------------------------------------------------------
    # The "spellCheck" function determines whether the input
    # from the inputFile is a correctly spelled word, and if not
    # it will return the word and later be written to a file
    # containing misspelled words
    #---------------------------------------------------------
    def spell_check(word, english):
        if word in english:
            return None
        else:
            return word

    #---------------------------------------------------------
    # The main function will include all of the code that will
    # perform actions that are not contained within our other
    # functions, and will generally call on those other functions
    # to perform required tasks
    #---------------------------------------------------------
    def main():
        # Grabbing user input
        inputFile = input('Enter the name of the file to input from: ')
        outputFile = input('Enter the name of the file to output to: ')
        english = {}  # Will contain all available correctly spelled words.
        wrong = []  # Will contain all incorrectly spelled words.
        num = 0  # Used for line counter.

        # Opening, Closing, and adding words to spell check dictionary
        with open('wordlist.txt', 'r') as c:
            for line in c:
                (key) = line.strip()
                english[key] = ''

        # Opening, Closing, Checking words, and adding wrong ones to wrong list
        with open(inputFile, 'r') as i:
            for line in i:
                line = line.strip()
                fun = spell_check(line, english)
                if fun is not None:
                    wrong.append(fun)

        # Opening, Closing, and Writing to output file
        with open(outputFile, 'w') as o:
            for i in wrong:
                o.write('%d %s\n' % (num, i))
                num += 1

    main()
```

Comment: Also, using python's with 'open(filename, type): ' is a much cleaner way of opening and closing files